# If $ f(x \cdot f(y) + f(x)) = y \cdot f(x) + x $, then $f(x)=x$

Tags: functional-equations, rational-numbers

Let $ f : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} $ be a function which has the following property:

$$ f(x \cdot f(y) + f(x)) = y \cdot f(x) + x \;,\; \forall \; x, y \in \mathbb{Q} $$

Prove that $ f(x) = x, \; \forall \; x, y \in \mathbb{Q} $.

So far, I've found that $f(f(x)) = x$, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(-1) = -1$.

(For $f(0)=0$, we substitute $x=0$ to arrive at $f(f(0))-yf(0)$ identically $0$ for all rational $y$; for $f(f(x))=x$, we substitute $y=0$ and use $f(0)=0$. For $f(-1) = -1$, substitute $x=y=-1$ to get $f(0)=-f(-1)-1$, and use $f(0)=0$.)

Comment: So far, I've found that f(f(x)) = x, f(0) = 0 and f(-1) = -1.

Comment: Considering the attempted answers below, certain steps in tackling this problem can be deceptively simple but actually difficult. So it would be useful if you could write out explicitly how you had arrived at $f(f(x))=x$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(-1)=-1$.

Comment: @KimJongUn Just simple substitutions. A clarification is good but I see no necessarity, since they are common routines in solving functional equations.

Comment: @WillardZhan Actually, I'll just add them myself.

Comment: what if f(0) = 1, and f(1) = y...so that f(f(0)) - y.f(0) = 0 is true?

Comment: f(0) can't be 1 because we have proved it's 0.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am questioning-> how does "f(f(0))−y.f(0) identically 0 for all rational y" imply f(0) = 0? I am saying, f(0) can well be 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equation we have is $f(xf(y)+f(x))=yf(x)+x$.

Set $x=0$ to get $f(f(0))=yf(0)\; \forall y\implies f(0)=0$.
Then set $y=0$ for arbitrary $x$ to get $f(f(x))=x\;\forall x$.

Now let $x=y=1$, to get $f(2f(1))=f(1)+1$. So pick $x=1,y=f(1)$ to get $f(1+f(1))=f(1)^2+1$, from which $f(1)^2+1=f(f(2f(1)))=2f(1)$, so $f(1)=1$.

Now set $x=1,y=f(z)$to get $f(z+1)=f(z)+1$, which can be used inductively to show that $f(n)=n$ for all integer $n$.

Finally, let $y=p/q,x=q$, for $p$ and $q$ nonzero integers. Then $f(qf(p/q)+q)=p+q$, applying $f$ gives $qf(p/q)+q=p+q$, from which $f(p/q)=p/q$, so we are done.

Comment: I like your solution. But I think you should also check that $f(z-1)=f(z)-1$ to obtain $f(z)=z$ for negative integers?

Comment: That's exactly the same relationship: you can use it to go both forwards to positive integers or backwards to negative ones

Comment: Very nice and clear solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have $f(f(x))=x$ it means that the function is onto

Furthermore, assume that $f(y_1) = f(y_2)$ for some $y_1 \neq y_2$

$$ f(-f(y_1)-1 ) =f(-f(y_1)-1 )   $$
$$\Rightarrow  -y_1 -1 = -y_2 -1 $$
$$\Rightarrow  y_1 = y_2 !! $$

Thus the function is $1$ $to$ $1$, its inverse $f^{-1}$ exists,
in addition to $f(f(x))=x$, we have $f^{-1}=f$

From above, you get $f(f(1)+1) = f(1)+1 $

$f^{-1} = f \Rightarrow f(yf(x)+x) = f^{-1}(yf(x)+x) = xf(y) +f(x)  $

For some $x_0=f(1)$, $f(x_0)=f(f(1))=1$ and putting $y=1$

$x_0 f(1) + f(x_0) = f(1 f(x_0) + x_0 )$ 
$\Rightarrow f(1)^2 +1 = f(f(1)+1) = 2f(1) \Rightarrow f(1)=1$

$\Rightarrow f(y+1)=f(y)+1$ by putting $x=1$ into $f(yf(x)+x)  = xf(y) +f(x)  $

From the original definition, putting $y=1$ gives $f(x+f(x)) = f(x) +x$

*Since $f(x)$ is onto, $f(x)+x$ is also onto(to be proved), therefore we can find $x$ such that $y=x+f(x)$ for all $y$ 
then $f(y) =y$*

**I cannot prove that it is onto... However, I found another way by looking at the answer of  Willard Zhan. He has proven $f(1/q) = 1/q$ for integers $q$**

For all $\frac{p}{q}$, it can be always written as $\frac{m+1}{q}$, where $m$ is also an integer.

putting $y=m$ and $x=\frac{1}{q}$ into $f(yf(x)+x)=xf(y)+f(x)$
$$f\left( \frac{m+1}{q}\right)=f\left( \frac{m}{q} +\frac{1}{q}\right) = \frac{f(m)+1}{q} = \frac{m+1}{q}$$ 
since we have proved $f(m)=m$ for integers. I think it completes the proof.

Comment: I would appreciate if the down-voter could explain what goes wrong with my answer :(

Comment: In general, I dislike downvotes and don't use to apply them most of the time. This case is one of them, yet you shoud perhaps explain a little more what leads you to conclude $\;f=\text{Id.}_{\Bbb Q}\;$ , even with $\;f^{-1}=f\;$ . There are infinite involutions on the rationals.

Comment: I agree with your comments, that is not a fact even if some points are specified. I gave a more detailed proof. I would appreciate if you could try to read it.

Comment: I downvoted on your first answer without explanation since I saw no evidence for it to be a right answer. Now for your edited proof, please show how you got $f(f(1)+1)=f(1)+1$ and I'll cancel the downvote, even though this is still not a robust proof.

Comment: One line before the end, how is that $\;f(1)^2+1=f(f(1)+1)\;$ obtained? I got lost.

Comment: $x_0 f(1) + f(x_0) = f(1\dot f(x_0) + x_0 )$  with $x_0 = f(1)$ and $f(x_0) = f(f(1))=1 $, thus $f(1)^2 + 1 = f(1 + f(1)) $

Comment: Ok. In fact, as my failed answer shows, $\;f(1)=x_0\implies f(x_0)=1\;$ I'm still lost though in the very last part: putting $\;x=1\;$ in $\;f(yf(x)+x)\;$ renders $\;f(yf(1)+1)=f(y+1)\;$ , fine. But then this equals $\;xf(y)+f(x)=1\cdot f(y)+1=f(y)+1\;$ , so how this last equals $\;y+1\;$ ?

Comment: I am sorry, it is wrong. I typed y without $f$ at the beginning and thought that I obtained the answer. I apologize for that. I should have written it down on a paper...

Comment: @mastrok Welcome to the club of mistypings and annexed mistakes. This shouldn't be very tough yet it becomes messy pretty easily with all those parentheses and stuff.

Comment: proof improved. Please have a look and thank you for tolerating my faults.

Comment: I cannot see why $f(x)+x$ is onto. Please have a second thought when you make claims.

Comment: You are right, I cannot prove it. I was inspired by your reciprocal relation and found another way.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(f(x))=x$, $f$ is bijective and there is a $y_0$ such that $f(y_0)=1$. Now we have
$$f(x+f(x))=y_0f(x)+x$$
$$f(xf(1)+f(x))=f(x)+x$$
which leads to $y_0f(x)+x=xf(1)+f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, or
$$(f(1)-1)x=(y_0-1)f(x).$$

Suppose that $y_0\neq 1$, then it turns out that $f(x)$ is a linear function. It is easily verified that in this case the only possibility is $f(x)=x$ which contradicts to $y_0\neq 1$.

Therefore we conclude $y_0=1=f(1)$, and as mastrok noticed we have $f(y+1)=f(y)+1, \forall y$, and equivalently $f(y-1)=f(y)-1,\forall y$.

The next step is for every $x\neq 0$, suppose $f(y)=1/x$ and we get
$$yf(x)+x=f(1+f(x))=f(f(x))+1=x+1,$$
and hence $y=1/f(x)$. That is,
$f(1/x)=1/f(x),\forall x\neq 0.$

Now consider the set $S=\{x\mid f(x)=x\}$. We already know $0\in S$, and $S$ is closed under operations 'plus one', 'minus one' and 'reciprocal'. Now I think it's easy for yourself to check $S=\mathbb{Q}$ by induction with an Euclidean fashion. There's an example here:
$$13/5\rightarrow 3/5 \rightarrow 5/3\rightarrow 2/3\rightarrow 3/2\rightarrow \ldots$$

**Update:** Since there are ones not familiar with Euclidean algorithm, I try to make it clearer. Use induction on $q$ for fraction $p/q\in\mathbb{Q}$, where $(p,q)=1$ and $q>0$. The Euclidean division turn out that
$$p=aq+b,a\in\mathbb{Z}, 0\leq b<q.$$
And $b/q\in S$ since $q/b\in S$ by inductve hypothesis. Now $p/q=b/q+a\in S$ and the induction is done since the initial case $q=1$ is trivial.

Comment: How do you intend to use Induction in a non well-ordered set as $\;S\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc I said Eulidean fashion. See my example.

Comment: I still can't see it "Euclidean fashion" or whatever. Either we have an inductive set or we have not one, otherwise I can't see how to end the proof formally.

Comment: @Timbuc Induct on the absolute value of the denominator.

Comment: Still the set isn't well ordered, as we have negative and positive stuff. Perhaps someone else can see it more clearly.

Comment: @Timbuc I'm not sure if you know Euclidean division. Simply $-13/5\rightarrow 2/5$ eliminates negative stuff.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of Euclidean division...I still cannot see it. Thank you, though.

Comment: I have heard about that as well. I agree that three actions together generates all rational numbers. I just gave a simpler proof based on your result of $f(1/q) = 1/q$.

Comment: @mastrok After you had those relations everything is fine. I just showed the most intuitive method.

Comment: thank you for offering me a chance to learn and think. upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
P(0, y): \; & f(f(0))=yf(0)=0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & f(0)=0. \\
\ \\
P(x, 0): \; & f(f(x))=x. \\
\ \\
f(P(x, y)): \; & f(x)+xf(y)=f(x+yf(x)). \\
f(y) \to y: \; & f(x)+xy=f(x+f(x)f(y)). \tag 1 \label 1 \\
\ \\
P(-1, -1): \; & f(f(-1)-f(-1))=-1-f(-1). \\
\Rightarrow \; & f(-1)=-1. \\
\ \\
x \to -1 \text{ from } \color {#4995CF} {(\ref 1)}: \; & -1-y=f(-1-y). \\
y \to -x-1: \; & f(x)=x.
\end{align}

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4349947/979028.

Comment: This looks wrong. If we put $x=-1$ into $(1)$, we get $-1-y=f(-1-f(y))$ instead of what is written by you.

Comment: You've made a mistake in your answer, plugging $x = -1$ in $(1)$, we get $$-1 - y = f(-1-f(y)).$$ 

You wrote $y$ instead of $f(y)$ thereby assuming $f(y)=y  \forall y$.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $x = y = 0$, we get $f(f(0)) = 0.$
Now, putting $x=0$, we get $f(f(0)) = yf(0)$  $\forall y$.
Hence, $f(0) = 0$ as well.

Substituting $y = 0$, we get that $f(f(x)) = x.$

Also, putting $y = f(y)$ in original equation, we get :
$f(xy+f(x)) = f(x)f(y)+x$.
Putting $x=y=1$ in this equation, we get $f(1+f(1)) = f^{2}(1)+1$

Now, putting $x=y=1$ in original equation, we get $f(2f(1)) = f(1)+1$
$\implies 2f(1) = f(f(1) + 1). $
But, $f(f(1)+1) = f^{2}(1)+1 = 2f(1).$
Thus, we get $f(1) = 1.$

Now, assuming $f(n)=n$ and putting $x=1$ and $y=n$ respectively in original equation gives us :
$f(n+1) = n+1$. Hence, $f(x) = x$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$ by induction.

Now, putting $x=1,y=-1$ in $f(xy+f(x)) = f(x)f(y) + x$, we get :
$f(f(1)-1) = f(-1) + 1 = 0.$
Hence, $f(-1) = -1.$

Now, putting $x=-1$ and $y=n$ in original equation, we get:
$f(-(n+1)) = -(n+1).$
Hence, $f(x) = x$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Now, putting $y = \frac{p}{q}$ and $x=q$, we get :
$f(q.f(\frac{p}{q})+q) = p+q$.

Applying f on both sides, we get :
$q.f(\frac{p}{q})+q = p+q.$
$\implies f(\frac{p}{q}) = \frac{p}{q}.$

Hence, $f(x) = x$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

So far we know $f(f(x)) =x$ and $f(0) = 0$. Differentiating $f(f(x)) = x$ on both sides gives us $f'(f(x))f'(x) = 1$ which implies $f'(0) = \pm1$. Now differentiating the orginal equation on both sides with respect to $y$ (keeping in mind $x$ is a constant with respect to $y$) we get $$f'(xf(y) + f(x))f'(y)x = f(x)$$.

Now plug in $y=0$ to get $f'(f(x))f'(0)x = f(x)$ and substituting the value of $f'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$ to get $f'(0)x = f(x)f'(x)$. This results to the differential equation $$f'(0)xdx = f(x)d(f(x))$$ and integrating both sides gives us $$f'(0)x^2 = f^2(x)$$

knowing constant of integration is $0$. Thus $f(x) = \pm \sqrt{f(0)}x$, which gives us $f(x) =  x$.