# Find $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(f(x)+xf(y))=x+yf(x).$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(f(x)+xf(y))=x+yf(x).$

My attempt:
\begin{align}
P(0, y): \; & f(f(0))=yf(0)=0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & f(0)=0. \\
\ \\
P(x, 0): \; & f(f(x))=x. \\
\ \\
f(P(x, y)): \; & f(x)+xf(y)=f(x+yf(x)). \\
f(y) \to y: \; & f(x)+xy=f(x+f(x)f(y)). \tag 1 \label 1 \\
\ \\
P(-1, -1): \; & f(f(-1)-f(-1))=-1-f(-1). \\
\Rightarrow \; & f(-1)=-1. \\
\ \\
x \to -1 \text{ from } \color {#4995CF} {(\ref 1)}: \; & -1-y=f(-1-y). \\
y \to -x-1: \; & f(x)=x.
\end{align}

I think I solved it, thanks for the help with the comments.

Comment: Not a complete duplicate, but see [If $ f(x \cdot f(y) + f(x)) = y \cdot f(x) + x $, then $f(x)=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171599/if-fx-cdot-fy-fx-y-cdot-fx-x-then-fx-x) for a headstart.

Comment: No, that's the same functional equation.

Comment: FYI, using [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(f(x)%2Bxf(y))%3Dx%2Byf(x)%24&p=1), I found dxiv's post.  On AoPS, there's [$f(f(x)+xf(y))=x+yf(x)$ Over the Rationals](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2573786p22111073). For positive reals, there's [Functional equation from real positive](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1854389p12521792) and [Positive FE](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2001267p13989326).

Comment: @SammyBlack Note dxiv's listed post is only for rationals, while the OP's question is for the reals, which is why it's not a complete duplicate. Similarly, my first listed AoPS thread is also just for rationals, while the other two are for positive reals.

Comment: Ahhh... thanks.

Comment: Maybe I've solved it... Can somebody check my solution?

Comment: @RDK It seems to be correct.